# Why is the list of generators changing generators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I have created a list of generators, as follows:

```
x = [1, 2]
axes = []
for axis_max in x:
    axis_grid = (i + axis_max for i in [2, 3, 4])
    axes.append(axis_grid)
print([list(gen) for gen in axes])
```

For some reason, the output from this code snippet is as follows:

> [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]

whereas I clearly thought it should output this:

> [[3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]

***Can you please help me understand why it happens, and how to fix it?***

(EDIT) **I now know why it happens now, but still don't know how to fix it using a generator expression, and not a function.**

Plainly, I can fix it by turning the generators into lists, as follows:

```
x = [1, 2]
axes = []
for axis_max in x:
    axis_grid = (i + axis_max for i in [2, 3, 4])
    axes.append(list(axis_grid))
print([list(gen) for gen in axes])
```

This snippet returns the needed

> [[3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]

but that is not what I want.

Comment: A generator function is by far the cleanest solution, but if you insist:  `axis_grid = (lambda axis_max: (i + axis_max for i in [2, 3, 4]))(axis_max)`